# Azure Function Json.Net Dependency Issue

Tags: json, azure

I have an Azure Function that deserializes a message from a topic:

```
#r "Lib.PosLog.dll"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Lib.PosLog;
using System.Reflection;

public static void Run(string message, TraceWriter log)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };

    var transaction =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionDomainSpecific>(message, settings);
}
```

The message has a dependency on a type from a custom DLL Lib.PosLog:

```
"$type":"Lib.PosLog.SaleBase, Lib.PosLog",
```

The DeserializeObject function fails with the following inner exception:

```
  InnerException: 
   HResult=-2146233088
   Message=Could not load assembly 'Lib.PosLog'.
   Source=Newtonsoft.Json
   StackTrace:
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.GetTypeFromTypeNameKey(TypeNameKey typeNameKey)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, String qualifiedTypeName)
```

I've checked the source code for GetTypeFromTypeNameKey and it seems to just call Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("Lib.PosLog"), which is returning null.

It then checks the current AppDomain for the type.

If I call Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("Lib.PosLog") before calling DeserializeObject then it works fine as it gets the type from the AppDomain e.g:

```
public static void Run(string message, TraceWriter log)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    };

    Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("Lib.PosLog")
    var transaction =    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionDomainSpecific>(message, settings);
}
```

So my question is why does LoadWithPartialName work when I call it in run.csx but doesn't appear to work when it's called internally by Json.net? I guess I'm missing something important. I'm also pretty sure that this used to work on Azure before updating the runtime version to 1.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that the referenced assembly doesn't get loaded as you don't explicitly use one of the types of this assembly in your function code, therefore deserialization fails because some part of the TransactionDomainSpecific type uses types of this assembly. The  Call to Assembly.LoadWithPartialName forces the load of the assembly, so it works. Could you try using one of the types from your referenced assembly in your code and see if it then gets loaded automatically?

Comment: Personally i think you would do yourself a favor if you switch to precompiled functions because you can reference assemblys in a more natural way via Visual Studio and also don't have mess around with uploading custom assemblys to the bin folder as they get deployed automatically with your function app and you can prevent errors like this from happening.

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152658/azure-function-could-not-load-file-or-assembly - have a look to check if it addresses your case.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this question and issue is from early 2017 (almost 2 years ago), I would assume it was a bug with Azure Functions that has long since been fixed. I use JSON.NET with Azure Functions all the time, both v1 and v2, without issues. :)